# add images into jar ,into specipic locate using ANT

Tags: java, ant, jar, insert

i am successfully inserting images into my jar file
but all images go to the root directory inside the jar 
how can i place image 
in a specific location inside the jar

this is what i have so far ,thank you

```
    <target name="dist" depends="compile" description="generate the distribution">
    <jar jarfile="target/jarFile.jar" basedir="${build}" update="true">

        <fileset dir="${src}/org/test/images/">
            <include name="**/*.png" />
        </fileset>

    </jar>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<target name="dist" depends="compile" description="generate the distribution">
    <jar jarfile="target/jarFile.jar" basedir="${build}" update="true">

        <fileset dir="${src}">
            <include name="org/test/images/**/*.png" />
        </fileset>

    </jar>
</target>
```

might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Is there a way to add multiple types (I'm thinking png and gif and jpg) ? Or do I have to copy and paste the include line and change just the extension.

Comment: Yes, and there's a shorter way.  If you want to include all types of images just use <fileset dir="." includes="images/**"/>